# Pyomo ValueError: Invalid constraint expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyomo

I am writing a pyomo integer programme with a constraint of the form:

```
def example_rule(model, j, t):
    value = sum(model.x[j,i]*(util[i][t]) for i in model.F)
    return 0 <= value <= 1
model.onelateral = Constraint(model.L, model.T, rule=example_rule)
```

`util[i][t]` is a dict containing values that are always 0 or 1.
`model.x[j,i]` is the binary decision variable.

Sometimes when I run my model, it works fine. However, sometimes when I change the dimensions/values within `util[i][t]` it throws this error:

```
ERROR: Constructing component 'example' from data=None failed:
    ValueError: Invalid constraint expression. The constraint expression resolved to a trivial Boolean (True) instead of a Pyomo object. Please modify your rule to return Constraint.Feasible instead of True.

Error thrown for Constraint 'example[L01]'
```

I cannot find any consistency in why it decides it doesn't like the input values for `util[i][t]`. There are never any null values in there.

If I run the model without this constraint in, it works fine all the time.

I have also tried writing the constraint in the form:

```
def example_rule(model,j):
    a = 0
    for t in model.T:
        n = 0
        for i in model.F:
            if model.x[j,i].value == 1:
                a = model.x[j,i] * util[i][t]
            if a == 1:
                n = n + a
    return 0 <= n <= 1
model.example = Constraint(model.L, rule=example_rule)
```

But I get the same error message.

I have looked here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pyomo-forum/hZXDf7xGnTI/_aiAUN5IwgQJ
But this did not help me.

I have tried this using both cbc and glpk solvers. I am using Pyomo V5.2, Python V3.6.1.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you have cases where util[i][t] is zero over all i's for a particular t? Terms that are multiplied by zero are automatically removed from the expression so I'm guessing your error is caused by a case where 'value' ends up as zero in which case 0 <= value <= 1 would return a trivial boolean value.

The easiest way to fix this is to formally declare `util` as a Param component and add `mutable=True` to the declaration. This signals to Pyomo that you might change the value of the `util` parameter and therefore avoids the automatic simplification of 0 values.

```
m.util = Param(m.F, m.T, initialize=util_init, mutable=True)
```

Another way would be to check the values of `util` and skip the constraint if an entire column is zero

```
def example_rule(model, j, t):
    if not any(util[i][t] for i in model.F):
        return Constraint.Skip
    temp = sum(model.x[j,i]*(util[i][t]) for i in model.F)
    return 0 <= temp <= 1
model.onelateral = Constraint(model.L, model.T, rule=example_rule)
```

Comment: Thank you @Bethany-Nicholson , that does seem to be the problem. I have no idea how to work round it... any ideas? I tried setting value to 1 if the summation solved to 0 but it wasn't happy with that.

Comment: This still makes no sense to me :-( After resolving it for this particular error (using the method in my below answer... which I have no idea why that worked), I am getting the same problem with another of my constraints. This time though, my answer below doesn't fix the issue. I can't understand why 0 constraints would automatically be removed? Is there a way of turning this option off?

Comment: @fishy321 I edited my answer to show two possible fixes

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by changing my constraint declaration to this:

```
def example_rule(model,j,t):
    return (0,sum(model.x[j,i]*(util1[i][t]) for i in model.F),1)
model.example = Constraint(model.L, model.T, rule=example_rule)
```

Unfortunately I do not know *why* this worked and the previous didn't!